# wp7 control with numbers rolling like a slot machine

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am writing a program for WP7 in C# where I would like to utilize a slot machine like effect where the numbers roll like they are mounted on a drum. Is there an efficient implementation of such a control? Any suggestions to implement such a control?

Answer (score 1):

In the [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) there is a DatePicker maybe you can check out that code to implement your own control. Maybe there is something in [phoneytools](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneyTools) you can use

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at some of the silverlight implementations on how slot machines effects have been implemented. This guys posts some [details on AppHub](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/501724.aspx). This guys implementation looks a bit old, [but it might help](http://weblogs.asp.net/hpreishuber/archive/2007/05/23/silverlight-slot-machine.aspx)